# Android - How can I set an item in a Toolbar to fill all of the available space?

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-layout-weight

I've tried assigning weights of course, but it appears that isn't supported by Toolbar.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the following to get rid of left margin in the tool bar

```
app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
```

So finally your code can be like this-

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/progress"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:background="@color/background_floating_material_dark" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**Edit**
You can do in the code also as-

```
toolbar.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0,0);
```

Even you can modify it in style too-

```
<item name="toolbarStyle">@style/Widget.Toolbar</item>

<style name="Widget.Toolbar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
<item name="contentInsetStart">0dp</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put a LinearLayout inside your Toolbar. The LinearLayout allows you to set an orientation and, once you've done that, you can use layout_weight.

So it would be like:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/progress"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:background="@color/background_floating_material_dark"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```